# Get JSON Column Names from ASMX Web Service

Tags: json, vb.net, asmx

I'm receiving this JSON from my WebMethod:

```
{
    "TableName": "myTable",
    "Table": [
    {
      "ProdOrder": "245392",
      "Item": "C01000FLS0300GF",
      "Qty": 40
    },
    {
      "ProdOrder": "245393",
      "Item": "C01000FLS0400GF",
      "Qty": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the WebMethod:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function MyWebMethod(strJSON As String) As String
    Dim objJSON As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(strJSON)
    'Get TableName
    Dim strTableName As String = objJSON("TableName")
    'Get Data
    Dim arrJSON As Object() = objJSON("Table")
    For i As Integer = 0 To arrJSON.Length - 1
        Dim ProdOrder As String = arrJSON(i)("ProdOrder")
        Dim Item As String = arrJSON(i)("Item")
        Dim Qty As String = arrJSON(i)("Qty")
    Next
    Return "OK"
End Function
```

Until here all is very simple and it works.

My question now is, how can I get the Names of the fields if I don't know them?

I mean, any way to get "ProdOrder", "Item" and "Qty"...

Using arrJSON(i)("ProdOrder") I get the Value. How can I get the title "ProdOrder"?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it:

```
Public Function MyWebMethod(strJSON As String) As String
    Dim objJSON As Object = New JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(Of Object)(strJSON)
    Dim strTableName, strFields, strValues As String
    For Each JSONItem As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In objJSON
        Select Case JSONItem.Key
            Case "TableName"
                'Get TableName
                strTableName = JSONItem.Value
            Case "Table"
                'Get Data
                For Each DataRecord As Object In JSONItem.Value
                    strFields = ""
                    strValues = ""
                    For Each DataField As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In DataRecord
                        strFields &= DataField.Key & ","
                        strValues &= DataField.Value & ","
                    Next
                Next
        End Select
    Next
    Return "OK"
End Function
```